# Why when you have two character array the first member of first array would not print?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have such code:

```
char num1[3];
char num2[3];
cout << "enter 1st num: ";
cin >> num1;
cout << "enter 2nd num: ";
cin >> num2;
cout << num1[0];
cout << num2[0];
```

Why num1[0] would not be printed on the screen but num2[0] would?
Thank you.

Comment: Given the size of the arrays I'd say when you input data into the second array (num2) it overwrites the first array (num1).

Comment: It's a bad idea to use the `cin >> ` with a char array (or char pointer) unless you also use length-limiting modifiers. This is just as bad as using `gets` or `scanf("%s"`.   Fix by doing `cin >> setw(sizeof num1) >> num1;` and similarly for `num2`. You may need `#include <iomanip>`

Comment: First of all, i should thank you for your response. I have tried what you said but when i enter the value of num1, for example 123, num2 won`t stay till i enter it`s value. '13' would be given to num2. Where`s the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you overwrite the first character of array num1 when you enter the value of array num2. As the both arrays have the size equal to 3 you may enter only two characters for each array.

For example if you will enter for array num2 value

```
ABC
```

and then press ENTER then the first character of array num1 will be equal to '\0' that is not displayable.

Comment: I thought when you declare num1 array as 3 you can use num1[0], num1[1] and num1[3]. Isn`t that true? Although my problem is solved with using 2 places of each array. Thank you.